# Calling external table from bigquery with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-drive-api

While I trying to reach the external table's data, I'm getting error like as below. I can not solve this issue. Here are the details about the situation;

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not found: Files /gdrive/id/id123456id

PS: id123456id is a dummy id.

The file with ID id123456 id exists in my Google Drive. Bigquery table looking this id.

bq_test.json -> service account credential's JSON file. This service account has those roles;

- BigQuery Data Editor
- BigQuery Data Owner
- BigQuery Data Viewer
- BigQuery User
- Owner

Here is my code block:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

scopes = (
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
)
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('bq_test.json')
credentials = credentials.with_scopes(scopes)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

QUERY = (
        """SELECT * FROM
            `project_name.dataset_name.ext_table`
            LIMIT 5"""
        )
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
rows = query_job.result()

for row in rows:
    print(row.name)
```

Comment: Sounds like the service account doesnt have access.

Comment: @DaImTo How can I give access? I cannot find drive.readonly or something else in the role list.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as follows;

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=PROJECT_ID
- Take service account mail value. ( like bq_test@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com )
- Go to https://drive.google.com and find the related file. (id = id123456)
- Right-click and choose Share
- Paste the above mail value. ( bq_test@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com )
- Choose read-only or whatever you need.

This flow provides the solution in my case.